# Handling http authntication in iOS

Tags: ios, http, cordova, client-certificates

I'm developing a corporate web application. 
The devices it is supposed to run on devices that have MobileIron and a corporate profile installed.
The app uses a corporate authentication service that authenticates based on client certificates. When I open the app in the Safari browser - the authentication is working properly. But in order to provide some of the features the app had to be wrapped in a PhoneGap shell. And the authentication has stopped working.
As far as I understand it is due to the fact that the UIWebView is unable to get the certificates from the device. 
Is there any way to entitle it to or implement the handling myself?

Comment: Maybe it's not much help - but what I would do is go native.

Answer (score 0):

Using MobileIron AppConnect, you can distribute certificates directly into those apps (instead of to the system keychain, which is only accessible to the built-in apps like Safari).  The app can then be coded to provide that certificate to the web server when challenged.  This is pretty easy to do.

http://support.mobileiron.com/appconnect will have the details.